# cin in while loop doesn't work properly (C++)

Tags: c++

This program should check if entered number is integer. It works fine with strings but not with doubles.

```
 int test;   
  cout << "Enter the number:" << endl;
  while(true) {
    cin >> test;
    if (!cin || test < 0) {
      cout << "Wrong input, enter the number again:" << endl;
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
```

Comment: You *do* know about the [`break`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) and [`continue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) statements, don't you?

Comment: The code is working correctly, everything is behaving as it should, but it's not doing what you want. The only way to do what you want is to read a *string*, check if the string is in the format of an integer, and only then *convert* the string to an integer. That's a lot of work, so unless you been told you must do that I wouldn't bother.

Comment: as @JoachimPileborg mentioned, don't user `goto` statement; it's considered to be a poor programming practice. Use `break` and `continue` statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is `int`. `istream` >> operator is just dynamic casting to int and, then, you're losing decimal part.

Yo can just define `test` as `float` and cast it to `int` when needed.

Edit: Answering you last edit (I didn't refresh so I missed this part), what is happening is that, without the `goto`you're looping twice:

1. You enter 1.5
2. `test` is 1 and you don't enter if, so `cin` is not cleaned up.
3. loops again and `cin` immediately returns.
4. `test` is 0 so enters if statement and complains.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int test;
cout << "Enter the number:" << endl;
while ( true )
{
    cin >> test;
    if (!(test < 0 || !cin))
        break;
}
cout << "Your chosen number is: " << test << endl;
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: No it's not, program not working. Enter "1.2" for example. break doesn't make any difference, I've already tried it.

Comment: Is it possible to use strings?